# Link or merge CHM files

Tags: numpy, python-sphinx, chm

I'm using [Sphinx](http://sphinx-doc.org) for my Python project documentation.  This is useful because I can export standard html documentation and Microsoft Help (CHM) from the same [rst](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ReStructuredText) source. However, I want to also include the [NumPy](http://numpy.org) chm help in my own project.  Is there a way to do this?

For example, I have the documentation for my project in separate .rst files. I then use sphinx to translate that text into a .chm file for distribution to Windows clients.  I also have a separate chm file for the NumPy documentation.  What's the best way to make the numpy chm reachable from my own project's documentation?

I would prefer having something in my own table of contents that links to the numpy chm.  However, I'll settle for some kind of hyperlink that users can click and open the numpy chm in a separate Microsoft Help window if needed.

Maybe there's a better solution I haven't even considered?

Comment: Best tutorial I remember you'll find at http://kb.helpwaregroup.com/ms-html-help/merge. A Windows machine with Microsoft HTML Help Workshop for compiling the CHM is required.

Answer (score 0):

Following solution may meet your requirements:

1. I compiled some HTML sample files into a ‘CHM-example-A.chm’ file using a Help authoring tool.
2. At the end of the corresponding file I added a section which contains a link to NumPy documents (see below - edited with NodePad++, ).
3. CHM compiled again and the resulting TOC and content:

[image]

In a connected world you may want to link to NumPy’s web directly like shown above. But of course – there is no Table of contents (TOC) in the navigation pane. Only a topic node is added here and no full text search is possible. The linked NumPy web content is shown inside the CHM Viewer content pane. Of course you can navigate here.

```
      <LI><OBJECT type="text/sitemap">
        <param name="Name" value="NumPy External Link">
      </OBJECT>
  <UL>
 <LI> <OBJECT type="text/sitemap">
    <param name="Name" value="Jump to NumPy documemts">
    <param name="Local" value="http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-dev">
    <param name="ImageNumber" value="13">
    </OBJECT>
  </UL>
```

Download the HTML sample files from following link and try to compile and add the nodes as shown above for your needs:
http://www.help-info.de/files_download/chm_example_files.zip
(For first steps with Microsoft HTMLHelp Workshop (Freeware) or FAR HTML). Or try by using your own CHM project files.

A hard coded Index item (like done for the TOC) is possible.

Linking CHM's is difficult and broken by security updates:
http://kb.helpwaregroup.com/ms-html-help/merge/notes

Linking to PDF (e.g. NumPy) from your Python project CHM may be a solution for you. See example Project for download from: http://www.help-info.de/files_download/CHM-example_project.zip

[image]